# How to send image to email as position absolute with html text

Tags: html, css, meteor, html-email, email

I'm trying to send the image as position absolute with the html text behind the image but when I send it to gmail or other email it show image then in bottom the html text. The absolute css is not working.

Below is the template

```
<template name="welcome">
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body style="font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;">
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <img src="http://qa.couchfashion.com/images/mailer.png" style=" position: relative;width: 100%;left: 0;">

    <div style="top: -44px;position: absolute;z-index: 999999;">
        <div class='mailer-name text-center' >
            <h3 style=" font-size: 80px;"> Hey {{receiverName}} </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="mailer-content" style="margin-top: 120px;
            text-align: center;
            text-align: justify;
            padding-left: 10%;
            padding-right: 10%;">
            <h1 class="text-center"> Welcome to the COUCH </h1>
            <hr>
            <h3 class="text-center"> How To use Couch? </h3>
            <h2 class="text-center"> STEP 1 </h2>
            <h3 class="text-center"> Browse Products &amp; Articles </h3>
            <p>Congratulations ladies! You've successfully made it to the first step of Couch. THis step is the
                easiest
                step. We are sure you will have great time browsing through our products and articles as we get you
                the
                best of them. We make sure best gets the best! </p>

            <h2 class="text-center"> STEP 2 </h2>
            <h3 class="text-center"> Collect things you Love </h3>
            <p>
                Hello again! So here we are on the second step. Well this is easy too. You just have to click on the
                love
                button to collect your favourite products and articles there. And there you go. You have your very
                own
                personalized collection. Woo-Hoo!
            </p>


            <h2 class="text-center"> STEP 3 </h2>
            <h3 class="text-center"> Get Appreciation </h3>
            <p>This is the best step. It will help you flaunt your beautiful talents ladies! People can see your
                closet
                and have a glance at your choice. Isn't that cool? You can promote your style and make it popular.
                Let's
                get started ladies!</p>
            <h3 class="text-center"> Thanks for signing up </h3>
            <h3 class="text-center"> All the Love &amp; Regards </h3>
            <h4 class="text-center"> Team COUCH </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS `position` is not supported in most email clients (both `relative` and `absolute`). Best way to achieve this is by making the image a background image:

```
<table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" aria-hidden="true" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="600" style="margin: auto;" class="email-container">
    <tr>
        <td background="http://qa.couchfashion.com/images/mailer.png" bgcolor="#222222" valign="middle" style="text-align: center; background-position: center center !important; background-size: cover !important;">
            <div>
                <table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="middle" style="text-align: center; padding: 15%ont-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px;">

                            >> Place your text layout in tables instead of divs <<

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

It's also still safer to use `<table>`s instead of `<div>`s for email, unless Gmail is the only client you have to support.

Answer (score 1):

Ted is right in his answer regarding that `table` is the way for structuring in email HTML. His solution is supposed to work well.

The reason you use tables instead of `div`s is that rendering engines have limited support for many properties in `div`s. Eg. Word-based Outlooks do not support `width` and `padding` on `div` elements without which it is impossible to define layouts. However these properties are well-supported on `td` elements. That is why we have to use tables.

If you go on using this method, there are a couple of best practices you should also follow:

- Set the `cellpadding="0"` and `cellspacing="0"` to avoid non-expected spacings by some clients.
- Use only one class for a HTML element. If you use multiple, then only the first will be applied.
- Don't use complex CSS selectors (eg. this will not work in Word-based Outlooks: `.bg-brown td { ### CSS ### }` . You should stick to simple class definitions.
- Lastly, background images only work in Word-based Outlooks in`td` elements, when you apply them with VML.

The code below is an example for  background images with text in front we use in our [tutorial about background images](http://blog.edmdesigner.com/background-images-in-modern-html-emails/).

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" 
      style="width:100%;min-height:50px; height:50px;border: ### 
      BORDER PROPERTIES ###" background="### SRC of BACKGROUND 
      IMAGE ###">  
       <tr>
          <td style="### FONT PROPERTIES ###">
           <!--[if gte mso 9]>
             <v:rect style="width:540px;height:50px;" 
               strokecolor="none">
             <v:fill type="tile" color="#363636" 
               src="### SRC of BACKGROUND IMAGE ###" /></v:fill>
             </v:rect>
             <v:shape id="NameHere" 
               style="position:absolute;width:540px;height:50px;">
           <![endif]-->
              <p>table background="...." + vml fixed width background</p>
           <!--[if gte mso 9]>
             </v:shape>
           <![endif]-->
         </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

Unfortunately, positioning is not covered, but it still may help to avoid some pitfalls. You can use Campaign Monitor's background tool to produce the VML code, or craft it on your own, based on corresponding tutorials.